# uploading an image to google bucket does not recognise it as an image anymore

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, bucket, vaadin14

I am using Vaadin 14 with SpringBoot. I'm writing some software that uploads an image to a google bucket. The upload itself works correctly but the file that gets to the bucket is not an image anymore. I wrote the code a couple of weeks ago and then it still worked, nothing has changed but now it doesn't work anymore. I am uploading it to the bucket using an InputStream, i get stream from the Vaadin upload component. Here is the code

uploading to memoryBuffer from vaadin component

```
public CreateKidView(@Autowired KidService kidService) {
        this.kidService = kidService;

        TextField kidFirstName = new TextField("Voornaam");
        TextField kidLastName = new TextField("Achternaam");
        DatePicker kidBirthDate = new DatePicker("GeboorteDatum");
        TextField kidMedication = new TextField("Medicatie");
        MemoryBuffer memoryBuffer = new MemoryBuffer();
        Upload imageUpload = new Upload(memoryBuffer);

        Button button = new Button("Kind toevoegen",
                buttonClickEvent -> {
                    saveKidAndNavigate(kidFirstName.getValue(), kidLastName.getValue(), kidBirthDate.getValue(),
                            kidMedication.getValue(), memoryBuffer.getInputStream());
                }
        );

        button.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);

        addClassName("centered-content");

        add(kidFirstName, kidLastName, kidBirthDate, kidMedication, imageUpload, button);
    }
```

then I pass the inputstream through a couple of other classes, I don't do anything with it until I get here: I set the contentType: "image/jpeg" and pass it to my bucketService to upload the inputstream.

```
public void addImageToPerson(Person person, String imageName, InputStream inputStream) {
        String image = bucketService.uploadFileToBucket(imageName, "image/jpeg", inputStream);
        ......
    }
```

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class BucketService {

    private final String companyName;
    private final Storage storage;

    @Autowired
    public BucketService(@Value("${company.name}")String companyName, @Value("${gc.project.name}")String gcProjectName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;

        storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(gcProjectName).build().getService();
    }

    public String uploadFileToBucket(String fileName, String contentType, InputStream inputStream) {
        try {
            BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(companyName, fileName);
            BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).build();
            storage.create(blobInfo, IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream));
            return fileName;
        } catch (StorageException | IOException e) {
            log.error("could not save image: {}", e.getMessage());
            return "oops";
        }
    }
}
```

it used to work perfectly, No code has changed since, so I'm guessing that something has changed at google. I was wondering if any of you have something i could try or know of something that has changed.

I have also written some code to test if the inputstream itself is valid, i display the image that i get from memory on the screen:
[image]

Thanks in advance :)

--edit

After more investigating i have found that the byte[] produced by the inputstream is different form the byteArray that is produced by the file itself:

```
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/Users/BartDuwez/Desktop/avatars-000338105915-u01ky6-t500x500.jpg"));
storage.create(blobInfo, content);
```

there is a difference of 1 byte: the very first one.

bytes: -40, -1, -30, ...

content: -1, -40, -1, -30, ...

I don't know anything about how this works.
To be clear the byte[] content displays an image correctly in the bucket!

when i check the buf inside the inputStream there is a byte[], that byte[] has the same inside as the content byte[]

if i do this in the debugger:

```
storage.create(blobInfo, ((ByteArrayInputStream) inputStream).buf);
```

a file gets uploaded and it works: but .buf is protected so i can't use it in my code. This makes it look like the problem is occuring when converting the inputstream to a byte[]

Anyone that knows something that could help me with this?